# How to modify the font of PhpStorm findbox

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

How to modify the font of PhpStorm findbox (find text field)? Fonts are windows default simsun! No change options in settings.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update**: this feature is available starting from IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.1. To make the search/replace fields use the editor font you can add `-Dide.find.use.editor.font=true` in `Help` | `Edit Custom VM Options` and restart the IDE.

---

Original answer:

At the moment the font used in the text field is hardcoded and you can't change it, please vote for this request and follow it for updates:

- [IDEA-106651](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-106651) Editor Search/Replace: use editor font for text input fields

Other related requests:

- [IDEA-68258](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-68258) Font in Find/Replace dialog and Find panel same as in editor
- [IDEA-125920](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-125920) Make the editor text search bar text-size & font an option.

Comment: Yes, I have set up but still no effect [images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONifw.png)

Comment: I've corrected the answer, it appears that editor font is not really used for this field.

Comment: I can confirm that it's still working like a (py)charm in 2019.2!

Comment: You could also use `Help | Find Action` from the main menu, type "Registry", press Enter key, and enable the `ide.find.use.editor.font` here.